# Is there any way to update Magento not use composer and Admin?

Tags: magento2, upgrade, magento2.3.5

I have try upgrade Magento use composer and Admin, but It show bug and I can't fix it. Is there any way to update Magento not use composer and Admin?

Comment: try to update manually.. check this link https://www.goivvy.com/blog/magento-2-upgrade
or https://amasty.com/blog/3-ways-to-upgrade-your-magento-2/

Comment: Do I need upload all files or only vender folder?

Comment: yes all files but keep backup first your exist magento files

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to upgrade Magento manually if you have advanced technical skills, or find a reliable Magento migration expert to help you perform the upgrade process because there are some differences in structure among Magento versions.